# How do I insert data to a disk table quickly on KDB?

Tags: kdb

I have five years of minute bars for around 10,000 symbols, as CSV files. It totals around 50GB of text. My RAM is 32GB.

I'm trying to load all this data into a KDB table, so it's easily queryable.

```
symbols: `$(-4_')(string') key `:/home/chris/sync/us_equities

f: {`$(":/home/chris/sync/us_equities/", x, ".csv")}

load_symbol: {(0!(update "P"$-1_/:t, s: x from flip `t`o`h`l`c`v!("*FFFFI";",")0: f(string x))) }

({`:/home/chris/sync/price_data insert (load_symbol x)}) each symbols
```

- Should I be using a straightforward table, or should I use partitions/splays?
- I'm adding the ticker as an extra column of type symbol; is that right?
- The last line, `insert`, is painfully slow. It looks like it would take around a day to process, perhaps longer. How might I optimize it? I tried `peach` but this was even slower. It looks like it starts out very fast, and gets slower with each step of the `each`.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a flat file is in this case is not recommended due to the data size and the frequency of updating it. The file needs to be recreated from scratch each time you insert leading to the insert time being linear to the total row count.

```
q)t:([]a:til 10000000;b:til 10000000)
q)`:t set t
`:t
q)\t `:t insert t
305
q)\t `:t insert t
365
q)\t `:t insert t
574
q)\t `:t insert t
809
q)\t `:t insert t
1236
q)\t `:t insert t
2687
q)\t `:t insert t
3200
```

Compare this to a splayed table, where each column in the new data is appended to the correspond file, resulting in constant inserts.

```
q)t:([]a:til 10000000;b:til 10000000)
q)`:t/ set t
`:t/
q)\t `:t insert t
166
q)\t `:t insert t
101
q)\t `:t insert t
97
q)\t `:t insert t
100
q)\t `:t insert t
111
q)\t `:t insert t
113
```

If the symbol is not already in the file then it would be wise to add it onto the table. However I would suggest naming the column **sym** instead of **s**. This is only due to it being conventional within kdb and that some built functions assume this name.

From my estimates, this table will be far too large for a simple splayed table. I would partition it by either date or month, depending on the types of queries you are running.

Sorting by sym and adding a [parted attribute](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/set-attribute/#grouped-and-parted) is a must if your queries will often select a subset of the syms. Sorting by time bucket within each sym is required to use an [asof join](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/aj/), as it uses binary searches.

The following code will do this, but as your files are already separated by sym, you should be able to skip the sym sort.

```
/ to sort a table in memory and apply parted attribute
update `p#sym from `sym`time xasc data 
/ to sort a table on disk and apply parted attribute
sym`time xasc `:path/to/partition
@[`:path/to/partition;`sym;`p#]
```

If your queries are more geared around selecting a specific time window across all symbols, you may be better sorting only by time bucket and apply a sorted attribute to this column.

Additionally you may want to consider streaming the csv files using [.Q.fs](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/dotq/#qfs-streaming-algorithm) or [.Q.fsn](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/dotq/#qfsn-streaming-algorithm) to reduce the memory usage of any single load. This would allow you to use multi-threading or additional processes to load in the data with the same memory overhead.

Comment: I've done what you suggested, including making sure the data has sorted `t` and parted `sym` flags upon `upsert`. However, I'm finding a simple query `select from disk where sym = ```AAPL` takes approximately 5.5 seconds, which is 8x slower than reading the CSV. I'm not sure what to expect to exactly. Looking in the folder, there's files for each column, but no extra folders (so I'm not really sure if it's parted correctly).

Comment: Just to add, the final file contains 160m rows.

Comment: You only need to apply the parted attribute `\`p` once when you are finished upsetting to the partition. You can check whether this has been applied properly by doing `attr get \`:path/to/partition/sym`. How are you timing this by the way? If using a client, it will be including the time to transfer the data across the wire

Comment: Wow, that's 4000x times faster! It's now much quicker than working with CSV.

Did ````p` just create an index on `sym` or is the data being re-arranged on disk?

I'm measuring the time with `\t`; it's all running on my localhost.

Thanks for your help by the way!

Comment: I'll add, I was unable to run `sym\`time xasc \`:path/to/partition` - it resulted in out-of-memory kill for KDB.

Comment: I would sort each CSV by time bucket as it comes in before inserting. When you have finished your data will already be parted by sym (as each file only contains a single symbol) so you do not need to sort by sym, you can just apply the attribute

Comment: I did that sort before inserting (it's definitely sorted); but I don't see a 'sort' flag on the meta for the disk db. Should there be one? (and if so, can I set it without actually running sort?)

Comment: Hi Chris. `\`p` essentially creates a hash map of each symbol along with the corresponding start/end. As the syms are in contiguous blocks, it can then just pull the whole lot. Moving onto your second question, although the data is sorted by time within each sym, considering the data as a whole the time is not sorted. If the time was sorted globally and the attribute wasn't there, you would have to apply it manually in the same way I suggested for parted